# Proof of $E[y(n)]=E[x(n)] \, \sum h(k)$

Tags: discrete-signals, homework, impulse-response, proof

> If $h(n)$ is the impulse response of the discrete LTI system, $x(n)$ is the white noise process with variance $\sigma_x^2$ and $y(n)$ is the output, prove that
>
> $$\mu_y = \mu_x \, \sum_{k=0}^\infty h(k)$$
>
> where $\mu$ represents the mean.

**My approach:**

$$\mu_y= \mathbb{E}[y(n)]
=\mathbb{E}[x(n) \star h(n)]$$
Where, '$ \star$' means convolution
Now how can I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard meaning of white noise includes an insistence (whether implicit or explicit) that the mean is $0$. Thus, what you want to prove is trivially true: since 
$$Y[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty h[n-k]X[k] = h\star X \big\vert_{n},$$ the *linearity of expectation* (the notion that $E[aX]=aE[X]$ and that the expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations) gives us that 
$$\mu_Y[n] = E\left[\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty h[n-k]X[k]\right]
= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty h[n-k]E\big[X[k]\big]$$
where all the $E\big[X[k]\big]$ have value $0$, and so both sides have value $0$.

More generally, if the $X$ process has constant mean $\mu_X$, then 
$$\mu_Y[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty h[n-k]E\big[X[k]\big]
= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty h[n-k]\mu_X = \mu_X\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty h[n-k]
= \mu_X \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty h[i]$$ is also a constant.

Comment: How $$E[\sum {h(n-k) * X(k)}] = \sum {h(n-k) * E[X(k)]} $$ $$?$$

Comment: _Linearity of expectation_ means that $\displaystyle E\left[\sum_k a_kX_i\right] = \sum_k a_k E[X_k]$. It is a _direct consequence_ of the generalized _[law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)._